# How can I rebuild Form Component in Codename One

Tags: codenameone

I'm trying to create Custom Form configuration with scrollable TitleArea. The Form (**black**) has a BoxLayout.Y_AXIS Layout in BorderLayout.CENTER (**blue**). StatusBar (**green**) stays in BorderLayout.NORTH (**green**), when rest of the TitleArea (**cyan**)  is in the first position in BoxLayout.

removeComponentFromForm function is unavailable for using in extended class. How can I remove components from Form to removing titleArea from BorderLayout.NORTH?

[image: plan]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use the title area at all? Why not just add a component to the top of the box layout Y and style it as a Title that way you can scroll it out?

You can also use the new `Toolbar` API that includes many abilities to fade out the title as you scroll etc. See:

http://www.codenameone.com/blog/toolbar.html

http://www.codenameone.com/blog/cats-in-toolbars.html